# How to add a WPF user control which is created in control library into Win-forms element host

Tags: wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

This is my actual requirement
I need to add a WPFmediaKit into a  already existing Winforms application.

So in-order to do that i need to add WPFcontrol into Winform's application.

My final objective is : A camera application with capturating , saving and mail features.

Answer (score 1):

Add `WindowsFormIntegration` reference , it gives us access to a control called `ElementHost`. This control is for WPF in WinForms what the WindowsFormsHost was for WinForms in WPF. In the designer, you can find this control in the Toolbox underneath "WPF Interoperability".

[image]